# I have created Jcheckbox in Jlist using DefaultListCellRenderer. how to deselect all checkboxes on button click

Tags: java, swing

I have created Jcheckbox in Jlist using DefaultListCellRenderer. How to deselect all checkboxes on button click. I have used list.clearSelection() in action performed method of another class but it is not working in my case. I have used following code for creating list with checkbox.

```
  // ListSelectionListener implementation
    public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent lse) {
        if (! lse.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            removeListSelectionListener (this);

            // remember everything selected as a result of this action
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            HashSet newSelections = new HashSet();
            int size = getModel().getSize();
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                if (getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                    newSelections.add (new Integer(i));
                }
            }

            // turn on everything that was previously selected
            Iterator it = selectionCache.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                int index = ((Integer) it.next()).intValue();
                getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(index, index);
            }

            // add or remove the delta
            it = newSelections.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Integer nextInt = (Integer) it.next();
                int index = nextInt.intValue();
                if (selectionCache.contains (nextInt)){
                    getSelectionModel().removeSelectionInterval (index, index);
                System.out.println("selection removed "+(index+1));}
                else{
                    System.out.println("selection added "+(index+1));
                    getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval (index, index);}
            }

            // save selections for next time
            selectionCache.clear();
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                if (getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                    selectionCache.add (new Integer(i));
                }
            }

            addListSelectionListener (this);

        }
    }
```

//code for list with checkbox.

```
    class CheckBoxListCellRenderer extends JComponent
        implements ListCellRenderer {
        DefaultListCellRenderer defaultComp;
        public JCheckBox checkbox;
        JLabel label=new JLabel("     ");
        public CheckBoxListCellRenderer() {
            setLayout (new BorderLayout());
            defaultComp = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
            add(label,BorderLayout.WEST);
            checkbox = new JCheckBox();
        //    add(i,BorderLayout.EAST);
            add (checkbox, BorderLayout.EAST);
            add (defaultComp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                   }

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                                                      Object  value,
                                                      int index,
                                                      boolean isSelected,
                                                      boolean cellHasFocus){
            defaultComp.getListCellRendererComponent (list, value, index,
                                                      isSelected, cellHasFocus);
          //  defaultComp.setAlignmentX(10);
            label.setText("  "+Integer.toString(index+1)+"  ");
           // defaultComp.setText("  "+Integer.toString(index+1)+"  ");
            /*
            checkbox.setSelected (isSelected);
            checkbox.setForeground (isSelected ?
                                    listSelectionForeground :
                                    listForeground);
            checkbox.setBackground (isSelected ?
                                    listSelectionBackground :
                                    listBackground);
            */
            checkbox.setSelected (isSelected);
            return this;
        }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating an array of JCheckBox and then adding them into the JList.

```
JCheckBox check1 = new JCheckBox("Check 1");
JCheckBox check2 = new JCheckBox("Check 2");
JCheckBox check3 = new JCheckBox("Check 3");

// Creating array of all check boxes.
JCheckBox[] array = {check1, check2, check3};
```

And now you can add them into JList using array or one by one, and whenever you want to deselect all JCheckBox you can do it by using this for loop:

```
for(JCheckBox element: array)
    element.setSelected(false);
```

Comment: we are dynamically adding items in Jlist. So check box is also dynamically added with items in the list. so how can we use array with it.

Comment: You can create an array of JCheckBox using the text you got dynamically. Everything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created Jcheckbox in Jlist using DefaultListCellRenderer.

Don't use a JList for this.

Instead use a single column JTable. A JTable supports the concept of editors and you don't need to write a custom renderer or editor.

All you need to do is override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your DefualtTableModel to return `Boolean.class` and the proper editor will be used.

Then you just add Boolean.FALSE to the TableModel. Whenever you click on a cell it will toggle between selected and unselected.

> How to deselect all checkboxes on button click.

Then you just loop through all the rows in the Table model and use:

```
model.setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE, row, 0);
```